# Is it appropriate to say "just checking in and see if there is anything that I can help with" to your boss in an email?

Tags: word-choice, tone

Is the phrase "check in" too informal to say to anyone other than your friend?  And the same question for "check back".  In addition, is there any other way to say "reach out" in a work email?

Comment: Whether something is **too** formal or is appropriate for this or that context is primarily opinion-based. For this reason, the question should be closed.

Comment: The grammatically correct for would be "just checking it **to** see..."

Comment: This question would be better suited to [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: *Is it appropriate to say ... to your boss in an email?* It depends on your boss.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something like "I've finished [assigned task]. What would you like me to work on next?" This acknowledges that your boss is in charge without implying they *need help.* Some bosses are very sensitive to this kind of thing.

Comment: Agreed, though it would definitely depend on the boss.

Comment: I've had some pretty insecure bosses.

Comment: I don't doubt it.